Discovered irrational slope in integer-based game
Studying the NIM Game, I've come to visualize the Winning State of the game on xy plane. The game's rules are:


The two pockets contain $n$ stones and $m$ stones each, and their contents are visible.
You can choose 2 options; pick stones as much as you want in only 1 pocket, or pick same amount of stones in two pockets.
A participant who picks the last stone wins.


I thought that visualizing the Winning State will help me analyzing the pattern, so I tried it (using Pyplot in Matplotlib).
And the result was:

(The dots mean the pair of the amount of stones left in each pocket after my turn.)
Then, I realized that the Winning State shows two 'lines', which are symmetrical about the line $y=x.$
So I now tried to estimate the tangent of two lines, and I got a value $\approx 1.618$.
...Alright, I thought this doesn't make sense. How does the integer-based game make the irrational number "$\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$"?
Moreover, I found that there is always the Winning-State point $(F_{2n}, F_{2n+1})$, where $F_n$ is a Fibonacci number($F_0=1, F_1=1$.). Maybe this makes the slope irrational, since the ratio of $\dfrac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}$ converges to the golden ratio.
Even so, I still don't get why the game makes the Fibonacci sequence. Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks.

This game is known as the Wythoff game https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wythoff%27s_game. The winning states are $(\lfloor n\phi\rfloor, \lfloor n\phi^2\rfloor)$ and symmetric.

@caduk Oh, I missed searching Wikipedia. Thanks for the comment answer!

Why aren't you surprised that the integer-based Fibonacci sequence models the irrational number $\frac12(1+\sqrt5)$?


This game is known as the Wythoff game. The winning states are ($⌊n\phi⌋,⌊n\phi^2⌋$) and symmetric.

Comment by @caduk, Posting as a CW to get the question answered.
